# Angularjs ui bootstrap modal : how to forbid background scrolling when a modal window is open?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

The scene is , when I click a button on page, the modal window is open on top of the screen. The background screen can be scrolling, the modal window can also  be scrolling. So when you click on the modal window, the modal window gets the focus thus you can scroll the modal window. However, when you click outside of the modal window, the background screen gets the focus, thus the background is scrolling. This is not what I want to see. We know when we use modal window in angularjs, we should inject **$uibModal**, just like the following:

```
 var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
        animation: true,
        templateUrl: 'templates/share.html',
        controller: 'shareCtrl',
        size: 'sm',
        windowClass: 'window-class',
        backdrop: true,
        resolve: {

        }
});
```

The **window-class** is very simple, see as follow:

```
.window-class {
    -webkit-transition: opacity .15s linear;
}
```

When we set the backdrop to **true**, it won't forbid background scrolling. Is there any method to forbid the background screen scrolling when a modal window is show?

Comment: can you provide details of "window-class"

Comment: I have editted the question, you can see as above.

Comment: For me its working. Can you provide plnkr. Please look into http://plnkr.co/edit/faa6Q8OG8V3Q6ZI04Sdn?p=preview.

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap adds a class `modal-open` to the `<body>`element when a modal is open. You can prevent the overflow scroll of the body by setting this simple css:

```
.modal-open {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```